# MySQL - Check if consecutive columns are the same and display only those rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `events` table that contains IDs (`id`) and dates (`eventDate`) corresponding to those IDs (`id` and `eventDate` are not the only columns in the table).

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4495c8/1).

```
+--------+----+---------------------+
| row_id | id | eventDate           |
+--------+----+---------------------+
|      1 |  1 | 2014-02-27 23:19:41 |
|      2 |  1 | 2014-02-27 23:21:41 |
|      3 |  1 | 2014-02-27 23:21:41 |
|      4 |  2 | 2014-02-27 23:23:08 |
|      5 |  2 | 2014-02-27 23:25:08 |
|      6 |  2 | 2014-02-27 23:25:08 |
|      9 |  3 | 2014-02-28 15:36:55 |
|      8 |  3 | 2014-02-28 15:36:55 |
|      7 |  3 | 2014-02-28 15:34:55 |
|     10 |  4 | 2014-02-28 19:31:31 |
|     11 |  4 | 2014-02-28 19:33:31 |
|     12 |  4 | 2014-02-28 19:33:31 |
|     13 |  5 | 2014-02-28 19:33:34 |
|     14 |  5 | 2014-02-28 19:33:33 |
|     15 |  5 | 2014-02-28 19:31:33 |
|     16 |  6 | 2014-03-04 22:40:21 |
|     17 |  6 | 2014-03-04 22:38:21 |
|     18 |  6 | 2014-03-04 22:40:21 |
|     19 |  7 | 2014-03-04 23:08:37 |
|     20 |  7 | 2014-03-04 23:08:38 |
+--------+----+---------------------+
```

I want to select only those rows from the table, where **consecutive** event dates are the same for the same ID.

Thus, I would like to see only these entries -

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | eventDate           |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2014-02-27 23:21:41 |
|  1 | 2014-02-27 23:21:41 |
|  2 | 2014-02-27 23:25:08 |
|  2 | 2014-02-27 23:25:08 |
|  3 | 2014-02-28 15:36:55 |
|  3 | 2014-02-28 15:36:55 |
|  4 | 2014-02-28 19:33:31 |
|  4 | 2014-02-28 19:33:31 |
```

Note that there is no

```
|  6 | 2014-03-04 22:40:21 |
|  6 | 2014-03-04 22:40:21 |
```

in the above result, because they're not consecutive.

I know I can store the output of the SQL query in a file and then use a unix tool to do this, but I want to know if this is achievable directly through SQL.

Comment: Is it that *positional* placement of the data in the table matters? Or just that there are multiple entries for a given date? For example, suppose that row 3 of your example occurred at the very end of the table. Would you still want the exact same output you give, or would you want to ignore the rows with `id` of `1`?

Comment: @EMS, good point. In my case, I realized it doesn't matter, but for the sake of this thread, suppose it does matter.

Comment: You can edit the question to reflect the fact that it is *grouping* by `eventDate` that matters to you, not actually positional consecutive repeats. Many folks may know very efficient and clever ways to do that grouping, whereas positional importance is a problem not well-suited for database systems (generally, not always).

Comment: @EMS, actually, I changed the question to reflect that the position does matter.

Comment: What determines how the records are ordered in the output. It seems like you should easily be able to change whether they are "consecutive" or not using some other key column or other property that you're not sharing.

Comment: To put it another way, why would the arbitrary placement of records chosen when indexing them have any bearing on this result. That doesn't make sense, and if it's just a pedantic exercise in how *would* you do things positionally, then it's not a very useful question to answer.

Comment: @Alexander, sorry, I didn't know how to use it. Will set it up!

Comment: @EMS, yes, there is something like row_id.

Comment: I've put an answer without row_id, as it wasn't in the original - its right at the bottom. I am confused as to why you have two rows with id 1 as the second one will not have a following row with same id and timestamp

Comment: @Wes I upvoted your answer for providing SQL Fiddle. I'll take a look later (probably tomorrow morning, it's almost night where I am) if you won't get an answer by that time

Comment: @Wes I have an answer to this problem that you are having along with a SQLFiddle that you should take a look at when you have a chance. Let me know if it needs adjusting.

Comment: Wes, Mic1780 totally did the job with his answer below. @EMS you can learn from him

Comment: @Wes so you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to accomplish this leveraging a group by although my mySql is a bit rusty.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
    SELECT  
           id,
           eventDate,
           COUNT(0) AS numRows
    FROM tabl
    GROUP BY id, DATE(eventDate)
    HAVING COUNT(0) > 1
    ORDER BY eventDate
) t
```

Then you just join this correlated sub query back to the original table if you need additional columns.

Comment: A habit of being in sql server world =P

Answer (score 0):

select id,eventDate from  your_tableName where eventDate in (select eventDate from your_tableName group by id,eventDate having count(eventDate) > 1);

Comment: Does not handle the consecutive issue

Comment: @vogomatix No it does not, it simply combines all like id and eventDate columns if there is more than one match. It would still include id 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ta.id, ta.eventDate from
(
    select row_id as ra, t1.id, t1.eventDate
    from events t1

) as ta
 join
(
     select row_id as rb, t2.id, t2.eventDate
     from events t2
) as tb
on rb = ra+1 and ta.id = tb.id and ta.eventDate = tb.eventDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to match the eventDate of the next row but the only drawback is that it will return the number of consecutive dates - 1 rows. But in your code you can just loop 1 extra time.

```
SET @inc = 0;
SET @innerInc = 1;

SELECT t1.id, t1.eventDate
FROM (
    SELECT id, eventDate, (@inc := @inc + 1) as increment FROM temp
) t1
WHERE t1.eventDate = (
    SELECT t2.eventDate FROM (
        SELECT eventDate, (@innerInc := @innerInc + 1) as increment FROM temp
    ) t2
    WHERE t2.increment = t1.increment
);
```

Here is the SQLFiddle for this: [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16b3f/36)

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to do it with a single table scan (no subqueries,joins,etc..)

```
SELECT t.id,t.eventDate
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF(id = @prevID AND eventDate = @prevDate, @counter, @counter := @counter+1) as c,
        @prevID := id as id,
        @prevDate := eventDate as eventDate
    FROM events e
    JOIN (SELECT @counter := 0, @prevID := NULL, @prevDate := NULL) as stuff
    WHERE 1 #or some where condition for events
    ORDER BY row_id ASC
) as t
GROUP BY t.c
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's not specifically that you need the *positionally* consecutive entry, but rather that if you grouped by `eventDate` and found entries with the same `eventDate` then you'd want those records, then the following:

```
select * 
from Table a
join (select eventDate, count(*)
      from Table
      group by eventDate
      having count(*) > 1) b
on (a.eventDate = b.eventDate)
```

The arbitrary dependence on the *position* of the data suggests that there is some other property you're not sharing, and it is by that property that the records are retrieved and ordered. If such a property determines the record's position, then it's precisely by ordering or grouping with *that* property that you can efficiently solve this.

Answer (score -3):

After throwing away my self-join I think you're going to have to generate row_numbers for each sub_query:

```
select @rn1 := @rn1+1 as ra, t1.id, t1.eventDate
from events t1
join (select @rn1 := 0) r;
```

and then join that to

```
select @rn2 := @rn2+1 as rb, t2.id, t2.eventDate
from events t2
join (SELECT @rn2 := 0) r;
```

so final answer:

```
select ta.id, ta.eventDate from
(
    select @rn1 := @rn1+1 as ra, t1.id, t1.eventDate
    from events t1
    join (select @rn1 := 0) r
) as ta
 join
(
     select @rn2 := @rn2+1 as rb, t2.id, t2.eventDate
     from events t2
     join (SELECT @rn2 := 0) r
) as tb
on rb = ra+1 and ta.id = tb.id and ta.eventDate = tb.eventDate
```

Results:

1   February, 27 2014 23:21:41+0000

2   February, 27 2014 23:25:08+0000

3   February, 28 2014 15:36:55+0000

4   February, 28 2014 19:33:31+0000